# How to have the same instance of a video in different view controllers?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I want to have a video in the background of my app, however i already did this by having all my classes inherit from this class

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {

var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var paused: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"video", withExtension: "mp4")

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: avPlayer.currentItem)
}

func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
    let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    p.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    avPlayer.play()
    paused = false
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    avPlayer.pause()
    paused = true
}
```

The problem is that when I change from view controller the video starts over again, and I don't want this, I want the video to continue from when it was in the last view controller, my solution would be instantiate one video and the access to it on all my view controller buy how can I do this? or is there another solution?

Comment: Context is important. For example, if you have embedded your view controllers within a navigation controller, it would make more sense to put your video player inside the navigation controller, with clear background color view controllers on top. This way you keep a single instance, and your video player is independent of the topViewController
Again, this one such option.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using Singleton.

Here's example:

```
final class VideoPlayerManager {
    static let shared = VideoPlayerManager()
    private init() { }

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var paused: Bool = false
}
```

To call in `viewDidLoad`:

```
VideoPlayerManager.shared.avPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `singleton` like this:-

```
class A {
static let a = A()
}
```

> And you can access the above object in multiple classes of the same
>   instance

```
class B {
func someMethod() {
 let a = A.a
 }
}
class C {
func someMethod() {
 let a = A.a
 }
}
```